# Download Helper creating empty files from all sites, not just YouTube

Tags: download-manager

Running Firefox on Windows 7.  Download Helper, beginning four or so days ago, began creating empty files. On all download attempts (e.g. Fox News), not just YouTube. Tried creating a new target directory (sub file of C/downloads). Also removed DH add-on from Firefox and installed it again; same result. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix?